# Problemas de insercion

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo el siguiente Problema:

quiero insertar varios registros a una tabla usando `javascript`, `ajax`, `php`, pero me da error al momento de insertar.

los `textboxs` tienen el mismo nombre que los parámetros de la función y los campos de la tablas tienen le mismo nombre y están en orden

quiero que revisen el código si estoy mal en algo

```js
function agregaestablecimiento(Nombre_Establecimiento,Direccion_Establecimiento,Nombre_Propietario,Apellido_Propietario,Numero_Identidad_Propietario,
    Telefono_Propietario,Correo_Electronico_Propietario,Ciudad_Establecimiento,Departamento_Establecimiento,Ubicacion_Especifica_Establecimiento) {

    cadena="&Nombre_Establecimiento=" + Nombre_Establecimiento +
           "&Direccion_Establecimiento=" + Direccion_Establecimiento +
           "&Nombre_Propietario=" + Nombre_Propietario +
           "&Apellido_Propietario=" + Apellido_Propietario +
           "&Numero_Identidad_Propietario=" + Numero_Identidad_Propietario +
           "&Telefono_Propietario=" + Telefono_Propietario +
           "&Correo_Electronico_Propietario=" + Correo_Electronico_Propietario +
           "&Ciudad_Establecimiento=" + Ciudad_Establecimiento +
           "&Departamento_Establecimiento=" + Departamento_Establecimiento +
           "&Ubicacion_Especifica_Establecimiento=" +   Ubicacion_Especifica_Establecimiento;

    //validacion de ingreso de datos con ajax
    $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"agregaestablecimiento.php",
     data:cadena,
     success:function (r) {
         if (r==1) {
             //mensaje de correcto
             alertify.success("Usuario Registrado Correctamente"); 
             //al momento que se agregue un dato se vuela a recargar la tabla
             location.reload(true);
         }else{
             //mensaje de error
            alertify.success("Fallo en el servidor");
           
           
         
         }
     }

    });

}
```

```html
<?php
try {
 //conexion a la base de datos
include 'conexion.php';


//almacena los datos ingresados en los textboxs
$Nombre_Establecimiento=$_POST['Nombre_Establecimiento'];
$Direccion_Establecimiento=$_POST['Direccion_Establecimiento'];
$Nombre_Propietario=$_POST['Nombre_Propietario'];
$Apellido_Propietario=$_POST['Apellido_Propietario'];
$Numero_Identidad_Propietario=$_POST['Numero_Identidad_Propietario'];
$Telefono_Propietario=$_POST['Telefono_Propietario'];
$Correo_Electronico_Propietario=$_POST['Correo_Electronico_Propietario'];
$Ciudad_Establecimiento=$_POST['Ciudad_Establecimiento'];
$Departamento_Establecimiento=$_POST['Departamento_Establecimiento'];
$Ubicacion_Especifica_Establecimiento=$_POST['Ubicacion_Especifica_Establecimiento'];


//Sentencia insert que afectara la tabla usuarios 
$sql="INSERT INTO establecimiento (Nombre_Establecimiento,Direccion_Establecimiento,Nombre_Propietario,Apellido_Propietario,Numero_Identidad_Propietario,
Telefono_Propietario,Correo_Electronico_Propietario,Ciudad_Establecimiento,Departamento_Establecimiento,Ubicacion_Especifica_Establecimiento) VALUES
('$Nombre_Establecimiento', '$Direccion_Establecimiento', '$Nombre_Propietario', '$Apellido_Propietario','$Numero_Identidad_Propietario', 
'$Telefono_Propietario', '$Correo_Electronico_Propietario', '$Ciudad_Establecimiento','$Departamento_Establecimiento', '$Ubicacion_Especifica_Establecimiento')";

//condicional para saber si el insert se ejecuto correctamente
if (mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)==TRUE) {
    echo 1;
} 

} catch (exception $e){
    //cuando mo conecte a la base de datos
    die("Error: " . $e->getmessage() );
}


?>
```

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Cual es el error que te da AJAX o PHP?

Comment: @alfap lo que intenta ahí es crear los parámetros `data` con el estilo tradicional en que se serializan los datos para postearlos, o sea, la notación: `clave1=valor1&clave2=valor2&claveN=valorN` a veces he visto código así que funciona, aunque para Ajax es mejor hacerlo algo así: `var data={clave1:variable1, clave2:variable2, claveN:variableN}`... Convendría que el OP indicase **cuál es el error específico que da el código**.

Comment: Si con **insertar varios registros** te refieres a en una sentencia crear varios registros lo estas haciando mal. Echa un vistazo a como se hace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query Aparte, tu código es muy vulnerable a Inyección SQL, usa sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo le dirá que no puede insertar valores vacíos porque no está bien formado el body que envía

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de

```
cadena="&Nombre_Establecimiento=
```

Pon

```
cadena="Nombre_Establecimiento=
```

Sobra el ampersan inicial.
Además, deberías usar sentencias preparadas, tal cual está te vas a encontrar sorpresas desagradables

Answer (score 0):

Sustituye:

```
type:"POST",
 url:"agregaestablecimiento.php",
 data:cadena,
```

Por esto:

```
 type:"POST",
 url:"agregaestablecimiento.php"+cadena,
```

Y como te menciona @david-moreno-cortina debes quitar el primer amperson ('&').